# Is a finite morphism of Deligne-Mumford stacks proper?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-stacks, algebraic-spaces

The situation that I am in is the following. Let $\mathcal{X}$ be a smooth Deligne-Mumford stack over a field $k$. Let $X$ be a $k$-scheme together with a morphism $\pi;\mathcal{X}\rightarrow X$ (you can take $X$ to smooth as well if it helps). Suppose we know that $\pi$ is a finite morphism. Can we conclude that $\pi$ is proper? More generally, can it be said for any finite morphism between two Deligne-Mumford stacks $\mathcal{X}\rightarrow \mathcal{Y}$?
It is definitely true for morphism between schemes, but I can't find any reference for my  query.

Comment: What is your definition of a "finite morphism"? Unless I am misremembering, you can take the definition to be "proper quasi-finite and representable".

Comment: @AriyanJavanpeykar I was following the definition given in stacks project https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0CHT. I could not find it in M. Olsson's book. Actually, in N. Borne's paper "Fibres Paraboliques et Champ des Racines" Corollaire 3.6, the author showed that the morphism from certain root stack to a scheme is finite, but hasn't defined what finite morphisms are. The paper is also in french, which is not my strongpoint. Do you know of any good reference for the definition?

Comment: I was using @Angelo 's famous article  Vistoli, A. Intersection theory on algebraic stacks and on their moduli spaces. Invent Math 97, 613–670 (1989). https://doi.org/10.1007/BF01388892 where on p.6 (=618) you can find "It is finite if it is proper and quasifinite". No need for representability, in this case the morphism isn't representable.

Answer (score 4):

The definition of finite being used is [from the Stacks project, representable and finite](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0CHT).

A morphism is proper if it is proper when restricted to an open cover (and finiteness is preserved by restriction to an open cover) so we may assume $\mathcal Y$ is a scheme (even an affine scheme). By the definition of representable, it follows that $\mathcal X$ is an affine space and $\mathcal X \to \mathcal Y$ is a finite morphism of algebraic spaces.

But now by [the definition of finite morphism for algebraic spaces](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/03ZP), $\mathcal X$ is an affine scheme and $\mathcal X\to \mathcal Y$ is a finite morphism of schemes.

The result then follows from the result in the case of schemes.

Comment: Isn't the default of representable in the Stacks project to be representable by algebraic spaces? This is one click away from your first link (definition of finiteness).

Comment: @R.vanDobbendeBruyn yes, good point. There's a mistake on the linked page, which I read too much into.

Comment: In case it confuses anyone (such as the person who downvoted?) I have now fixed the issue Remy pointed out.